# CriteriaQuery join on string value

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa

I have a table with a string value for the barcode of the entity it points to. Unfortunately, it is not a foreign key, its just a string, so no mapping exists. This makes join operations difficult. I was wondering how I could go about joining this object to another table where no relationship is defined. For example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TblSample", schema = SCHEMA, catalog = CATALOG)
public class Sample {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "barcodeEntity", nullable = false)
  private String barcodeEntity;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "barcodeContainer", nullable = false)
  private Container container;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TblSoil", schema = SCHEMA, catalog = CATALOG)
public class Soil {

  @Column(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
  private String barcode;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
  ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TblLeaf", schema = SCHEMA, catalog = CATALOG)
public class Leaf {

  @Column(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
  private String barcode;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TblContainer", schema = SCHEMA, catalog = CATALOG)
public class Container {

  @Column(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
  private String barcode;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "location", nullable = false)
  private String location;
  ...
}
```

Therefore, I would like to use a CriteriaQuery can return all the sample and join on the entities that it is taken from. I have started to write it, but I got stuck when I tried to figure out how to do it. In sql it would like something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100
  sample.Id
, sample.barcodeEntity
, leaf.name
, soil.name
, sample.barcodeContainer
, container.name
, container.location
FROM TblSample sample

  LEFT JOIN TblSoil leaf on
    soil.barcode = sample.barcodeEntity

  LEFT JOIN TblLeaf leaf on
    leaf.barcode = sample.barcodeEntity

  JOIN TblContainer container on
    container.barcode = sample.barcodeContainer
```

I guess that the associated jpa CriteriaQuery would look something like this:

```java
public void findSamples(Map<String, String> filterCriteria) {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<SampleLocation> query = builder.createQuery(SampleLocation.class);
    final Root<Sample> derivation = query.from(Sample.class);
    // Note that the next two lines don't work 
    final Join<Leaf> joinOnLeaf = derivation.join(Sample_.barcodeEntity, JoinType.LEFT);
    final Join<Soil> joinOnSoil = derivation.join(Sample_.barcodeEntity, JoinType.LEFT);
    final Join<Container> joinOnContainer = derivation.join(Sample_.barcodeContainer);

    CompoundSelection<SampleLocation> cSelect = 
      builder.construct(SampleLocation.class, sample.Id, sample.entitybarcode, joinOnLeaf.get(Leaf_.name), joinOnLeaf.get(Soil_.name), sample.barcodeContainer, joinOnContainer.get(Container_.name), joinOnContainer.get(Container_.location));
    query.select(cSelect);

    TypedQuery<SampleLocation> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(100);

    return typedQuery.getResults();
}
```

Any ideas how I can perform the left join operations? I can't make out how to do it based on the CriteriaQuery api. Seems like something that should exist.

Comment: To be honest, I resort to HQL once the queries get this complex (assuming it's Hibernate that you're using...)

Comment: As a last resort I'll probably try this. However, I'd prefer not to since its not type safe. We're mostly Java developers here so we're more comfortable performing DB work from that standpoint. Having said that this maybe one of those exceptional cases. If I can't get this to work with JPA, then I think we'll work on a separate project that performs complex queries (such as this) to isolate it from the rest of the code base. Once you introduce SQL into your code base it can become really difficult to maintain (as I've discovered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two queries.  For the first one, get the primary key value(s) that co-incide with your barcode string.  Then use the data from your first query in your second one.

Comment: I was hoping to do it in one go, but you're probably right. Maybe I can convince the DBA to change the table to use foreign keys instead of just barcode strings. It would make life a lot easier.